# display Json in html+node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I need to display in a html page the results of a GET request to a mysql database which are given in JSON format. I am using express js with bootstrap and I am basically asking how to display the results of a GET request done in node.js in a html page.
This is the code that performs the GET request, tell me if I have to be more clear please

```
app.route('/zigbee/:action').get(function (req, res) {
  var connectionZ = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : '',
    password : '',
    database : 'ZigBeeNetwork'
  });
connectionZ.connect();

  if (req.param('action') == 'zi') {
    //route utilizzata per inserire dati, la data è inserita automaticamente tramite la funzione Date()
    name = req.param('name');
    temp = req.param('temp');
    hum = req.param('hum');
    date = Date();

    if(!name){name = null;}
    if(!temp){temp = null;}
    if(!hum){hum = null;}
    var queryString = 'INSERT INTO ZigBeeTH (id, Arduino, Temp, Hum, Data) VALUES (NULL, "'+name+'", '+temp+', '+hum+', "'+date+'")';
    connectionZ.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
    else{
    console.log('Query performed');
    res.send('Query performed');
    }
    });
  }
  if (req.param('action') == 'zs') {
    //route per cercare dei dati basandosi su nome e temperatura
    name = req.param('name');
    temp = req.param('temp');
    hum = req.param('hum');
    date = Date();
    var app='';

    if (name) {
    app += 'Arduino="'+name+'"';
    }

    if(temp) {

      if(app) {
        app+=' AND ';
      }
      app += 'Temp="'+temp+'"';
    }
    if(hum){
      if(app) {
        app+=' AND ';
      }
      app += 'Hum="'+hum+'"';
    }
    var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM ZigBeeTH WHERE '+app;
    console.log('Test '+queryString );
    connectionZ.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

    var JSONObject = JSON.stringify(rows);
    res.send(JSONObject);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You are using express then Use EJS as view engine  and inside your main node module i.e. app.js use route to fetch the data it will make your life easier and write JavaScript in html from which you can display the results in view in grid or whatever.

Comment: even if I must not use html5?

Comment: Lol just use Ajax in html.